# Excanvas: Can I use Processing.js with it at near-normal (for <canvas>) speeds?

Tags: performance, frame-rate, excanvas

I've recently come across Google's Excanvas stuff... It's all very well and good having `<canvas>` for the turdier browsers out there, but I was wondering how optimised it was; can I use processing.js on it (probably) and get framerates close to those I'd get on a native canvas in something like Chrome/FireFox?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will mostly depend on the sturdiness of the machine your code gets executed on, and the speed of the javascript interpreter that will run your code.

ExtCanvas means extra overhead, and some versions of Chrome and Firefox support hardware acceleration of their canvas rendering.

This makes it unlikely that using ExtCanvas will yield the same results (as far as speed is concerned) as a canvas tag

Comment: Thanks. I suppose the best way is just to experiment.

Comment: Keep me up to speed if you can please, this is interesting stuff :)